# What is the foreign key between two children in the same hierarchy?

Tags: database-design

I'm trying to map an entity relationship design into a relational database. Under STAFF entity, I have 2 children are BUSINESS MANAGER and EMPLOYEE.

My teacher requests to add a 1-M relationship SUPERVISE between Business_MGR and EMPLOYEE (a BUSINESS-MGR supervises 0, 1, or more employees, an EMPLOYEE is always supervised by one BUSINESS-MGR).

What is the foreign key for the EMPLOYEE entity?

Answer (score 1):

The id of a manager that you store in the supervisor column of employee.